# Plot several fields in an image

Tags: python-3.x, astropy, fits

How would I plot several FITS fields in a single image ? Each FITS file covers a neighboring part of the sky.

The `data` field of the HDU only contains the image. So to plot each image at the right coordinates, I need to get information from the `header` field. But how do I pass that information on the pyplot?

I tried the following, using `astropy.WCS` so that the information from the headers be used in the plots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS

image_files = ['file1.fits', 'file2.fits']
for image_file in image_files:
    image_header = fits.open(image_file)[0].header  # extract header info
    image_data = fits.getdata(image_file, ext=0)

    # use the WCS class to get coordinate info and projection axes to use
    wcs = WCS(image_header)

    ax = plt.subplot(projection=wcs)
    im = ax.imshow(image_data, origin='lower')
```

This only shows the last image.

---

I'm expecting something like this:

[image: expected result]

where both parts of the image come from different fits files which are

[image: file1]

and

[image: file2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [Montage software](http://montage.ipac.caltech.edu/news.html). There is a Python wrapper for it called `montage-wrapper`. The [mosaic](https://montage-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.5/_generated/montage_wrapper.wrappers.mosaic.html#montage_wrapper.wrappers.mosaic) function produces a new FITS image by juxtaposing several FITS images. That new FITS file can then be read and plotted.

```
import montage_wrapper as montage

montage.mosaic(input_directory, output_directory)

hdu = fits.open(filename)
image_header = hdu[0].header
image_data = hdu[0].data

wcs = WCS(image_header)
ax = plt.subplot(projection=wcs)
im = ax.imshow(image_data, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

where `input_directory` contains `file1.fits` and `file2.fits`.

Comment: You should try http://reproject.readthedocs.org/, which uses the same algorithm as montage but is being more actively maintained (it's by the same developer)

Comment: @keflavich By using the `reproject_interp` function then plotting both images in the same figure?

Comment: yes, or reproject_exact; you can just use reproject instead of montage