# What is the difference between reproject and montage mosaicing utilities?

Tags: python, astropy

The Python modules [montage-wrapper](https://montage-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.5/_generated/montage_wrapper.wrappers.mosaic.html#montage_wrapper.wrappers.mosaic) and [reproject](https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/reproject.reproject_exact.html#reproject.reproject_exact) both have a function that makes it possible to make a mosaic of two or more images.

From the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987729/3128109), I learned that it is better to use reproject, but that opens a new question. What are the differences between these two functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reproject` does what its name suggests: it reprojects pixel data from a single image to a new image with a different scale and/or orientation. If you look at the example they show in the QuickStart, this converts the MSX infrared (E band, ~21 microns) image which is in galactic co-ordinates with a pixel scale of ~24"/pixel to the same scale and orientation as a 2MASS infrared (K band, ~2.2 microns) image in RA, Dec co-ordinates with ~5"/pixel pixel scale.

`montage`, and its wrapper, also does this reprojection but can also perform mosaicing where you combine multiple images, normally with some (~20%), overlap into a single larger image.

I didn't see anything in the `reproject` documentation that states that it can handle multiple images i.e. the mosaicing part.